# Displaying a view of device app camera on an wear in android

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api, android-watch

The clock wants to show you the camera screen of the mobile phone app, but I can't find a way, and one way I found it is a five-second delay

I've tried and searched in various ways to show my cell phone camera preview to my watch, but `Wearable.getMessageClient(context). sendMessage()`. We only found a way to send and display information in the frame using the sendMessage() method. In addition, the performance of this method is so low that the response rate is delayed by 5 seconds. Currently, we are using `GLSurface` and `textureview` to easily show the camera screen with `addTarget()` in the mobile phone app. Is there a way to use this method in the watch as well? Or is there a way to mirror my phone camera preview without delay like the default watch camera app?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: From: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data/data-layer did you see `ChannelClient` where `Transfer streamed data, such as voice data from the microphone.`

Comment: @MorrisonChang I checked the document. I didn't check it because I thought there would be a delay problem like MessageClient even if I use ChannelClient, but I will check it. For your information, the sample I checked is github.com/Aghajari/OpWear-Cam/tree/main